# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I am getting this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess` when the debugger goes to XML validation connector it is throwing this error. Please help me with this.

Comment: Which exact version of Studio and Mule runtime are you using?

Comment: @[aled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721855/aled) studio is 7.6.0 and Mule Runtime is 4.3.0 EE

Comment: It could be a bug of the validation module. Please add to the question: a) complete error message with detailed stack trace (you might need to define Java property `-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true` for the detailed stack), b) version of the validation module used by the application.

Comment: Got it, one of the plugins referred had mismatched version for the module, thanks anyways.

Comment: Please post the solution so others can benefit of your experience.

Comment: Downvoting the question, since the OP did not provide info on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Dependencies in your Application's pom.xml and make sure if you are using any plugins all the modules in the plugin have same version as your API's modules. In my case I was using an xml module where the version was 1.2.3 in the plugin and 1.2.2 in my Application