# ActiveMQ Artemis: custom login module not working from 2.17.0

Tags: jaas, activemq-artemis

I am running an ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0 server to which I developed a custom login module to authenticate against my own authorization server. It worked perfectly so far.

Now that I have upgraded to 2.17.0 and 2.18.0 I am getting following exception:

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222216: Security problem while authenticating: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:61432. Username: technical; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

My `login.config` file looks like this:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
       
   com.dallmeier.asa.security.artemis.MyLoginModule sufficient
       logEnabled=true
       authUrl="http://localhost:5561/auth"
       onSuccessRole="amq"
       cacheDurationMinutes="3"
       cacheSize="10000";

};
```

The plugin implements `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`. It initializes a Singleton instance of a class `ValidationSupplier`. This executes simple `http` requests and caches the user for 5 minutes with:

```
com.google.common.cache.Cache;
com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
```

It looks like it is something with the cache. Why it is a problem? When I am not using it it works.

```java
public class CachingAdapter {

    private Cache<String, IAuthPrincipal> tokenCache;
    private ValidationSupplier coreSupplier;

    public CachingAdapter (long cacheDurationMinutes, long cacheSize, ValidationSupplier coreSupplier) {
        this.tokenCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(cacheSize)
                .expireAfterWrite(cacheDurationMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
        this.coreSupplier = coreSupplier;
    }

    public IAuthPrincipal validate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        return this.tokenCache.get(username, () -> coreSupplier.validate(username, password));
    }
}
```

```
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager] Couldn't validate user: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3472)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3476)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2134)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4848)
```

Comment: I updated my post with the code snippet, in which I am requesting the cache. I also turned on DEBUG level for ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager . Apparently a class belongig to guava can not be found: DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager] Couldn't validate user: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess [...]

Comment: I have read somewhere in artemis release notes of 2.15.0 or 2.16.0, that artemis enabled credentials caching for performance reasons. And indeed, from my logs I can see, that artemis is using my login plugin not or every incoming request. Maybe I can remove my caching then?

Comment: I removed the additional caching mechanism, so it works now. But the actual problem that the class can not be found - even though I am using exactly the same dependencies as artemis - is still not clear. I checked all my dependcies versions in pom.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17 has updated the guava version from 24.1.1-jre to 30.1-jre. Using guava version 30.1-jre to build the custom login module, should fix the issue.

Comment: I am using the guava dependency with scope provided, so that it is used from artemis lib folder. Using the same sources for it: org.apache.activemq.artemis-cli, org.apache.activemq.artemis-server, org.apache.activemq.artemis-boot

Answer (score 0):

Caching for authentication and authorization data was [added in 2.16.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2160). Therefore, it's not clear why your login module would need its own caching. I'm not sure why you're getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608914/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-common-util-concurrent-internal-inter) might help.

In any case, I recommend you remove your caching mechanism and simply use the broker's caching. You can read more about configuration for this caching in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html).